# import csv into neo4j missing node

Tags: csv, graph, neo4j

I want to import the following CSV files into neo4j

```
:START_ID,:END_ID,:TYPE
1, 2, call
2, 3, text
3, 2, text
6, 3, text
5, 6, text
5, 4, call
4, 1, call
4, 5, text
1, 5, call
1, 8, call
6, 8, call
6, 8, text
8, 6, text
7, 1, text
```

and

```
person:ID,name,value:int
1,Alice,1
2,Bob,0
3,Charlie,0
4,David,0
5,Esther,0
6,Fanny,0
7,Gabby,0
8,XXX,1
```

imported via

```
DATA_DIR_SAMPLE=/data_network/
$NEO4J_HOME/bin/neo4j-admin import --into ${NEO4J_HOME}/data/databases/social.db \
  --nodes:Person ${DATA_DIR_SAMPLE}/v.csv \
  --relationships ${DATA_DIR_SAMPLE}/e.csv \
  --ignore-empty-strings true \
  --skip-duplicate-nodes true \
  --skip-bad-relationships true \
  --bad-tolerance  1500 \
  --multiline-fields=true
```

is telling me, that all relationships contain missing nodes. What is wrong here?

```
InputRelationship:
   source: /data_network/e.csv:2
   startNode: 1 (global id space)
   endNode:  2 (global id space)
   type:  call
 referring to missing node  2
InputRelationship:
   source: /data_network/e.csv:3
   startNode: 2 (global id space)
   endNode:  3 (global id space)
   type:  text
 referring to missing node  3
InputRelationship:
   source: /data_network/e.csv:4
   startNode: 3 (global id space)
   endNode:  2 (global id space)
   type:  text
 referring to missing node  2
InputRelationship:
   source: /data_network/e.csv:5
   startNode: 6 (global id space)
   endNode:  3 (global id space)
   type:  text
 referring to missing node  3
InputRelationship:
   source: /data_network/e.csv:6
   startNode: 5 (global id space)
   endNode:  6 (global id space)
   type:  text
 referring to missing node  6
InputRelationship:
   source: /data_network/e.csv:7
   startNode: 5 (global id space)
   endNode:  4 (global id space)
   type:  call
 referring to missing node  4
InputRelationship:
   source: /data_network/e.csv:8
   startNode: 4 (global id space)
   endNode:  1 (global id space)
   type:  call
 referring to missing node  1
InputRelationship:
   source: /data_network/e.csv:9
   startNode: 4 (global id space)
   endNode:  5 (global id space)
   type:  text
 referring to missing node  5
InputRelationship:
   source: /data_network/e.csv:10
   startNode: 1 (global id space)
   endNode:  5 (global id space)
   type:  call
 referring to missing node  5
InputRelationship:
   source: /data_network/e.csv:11
   startNode: 1 (global id space)
   endNode:  8 (global id space)
   type:  call
 referring to missing node  8
InputRelationship:
   source: /data_network/e.csv:12
   startNode: 6 (global id space)
   endNode:  8 (global id space)
   type:  call
 referring to missing node  8
InputRelationship:
   source: /data_network/e.csv:13
   startNode: 6 (global id space)
   endNode:  8 (global id space)
   type:  text
 referring to missing node  8
InputRelationship:
   source: /data_network/e.csv:14
   startNode: 8 (global id space)
   endNode:  6 (global id space)
   type:  text
 referring to missing node  6
InputRelationship:
   source: /data_network/e.csv:15
   startNode: 7 (global id space)
   endNode:  1 (global id space)
   type:  text
 referring to missing node  1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding an additional 
    :LABEL
column is fixing this.

Comment: Which file did you have to add the `:LABEL` column to fix this?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not remember. But try on both.

Comment: So there is still no answer to the question

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `:LABEL` column to the node csv file in order to tell `neo4j` what label are you creating for the nodes. It should look something like this:

```
person:ID,name,value:int,:LABEL
1,Alice,1,person
2,Bob,0,person
3,Charlie,0,person
.
.
.
```

And then you need to mention that the you're connecting the nodes with the label `person` in the relationship file.

```
:START_ID(person),:END_ID(person),:TYPE
1, 2, call
2, 3, text
3, 2, text
.
.
.
```

NOTE: You can give any other label instead of `person`.